# getting error in this line AccountFeed accountFeed = service.Query(query); in google analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

1. What to pass in this method, where to create this Analytic services 
   AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("??????");

2.i want to display google analytics reporting audience overview in
    aspx web page  . has anyone tried this ? can u send any sample code
    ?
 3. i want to display Sessions, users,Page Views,Page Session, Avg.
    Session Duration,Bounce rate of web pages of google analytics .
 4. Do u have any relevant code for this ?
. getting error in this line -  AccountFeed accountFeed = service.Query(query);

error - Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Int32 _intVisists = 0;
    Int32 _intPageViewVisit = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         RefreshFeed();
    }
    private void RefreshFeed()
    {
        // your Google analytics username and password here
        string userName = "550786864234-3b7j6fs5d8178n36coc1seoshlqf8nlu@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        string passWord = "s-fP2XFJNYDkMPoCm5o61Cpp";
        const string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";


        AccountQuery query = new AccountQuery();
        AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("AnalyticsSampleApp");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);
        }
        string str = "";
        AccountFeed accountFeed = service.Query(query);
        foreach (AccountEntry entry in accountFeed.Entries)
        {
            str = entry.ProfileId.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the [google-api-dotnet-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) is for a min of .net 4.0.  So if you can't use .net 4.0 you cant use Google's nice Client library.

All the client library does is makes things easer you can connect to Google Analytics with Oauth2 manually without using the client library.  I have done personally had to do this on several projects, because I had to support .net 3.5.

The hardest part of all of this will be the authentication.  It's in 3 parts you will probably need to use a web browser control, it's what I found the easiest.

The code for all of this is quite extensive.  I have an old tutorial on it its one of my first and hasn't been update in a while you are welcome to have a look it may help you get started.   [Google API and Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/)